# How do i extract the first number

Tags: java

so basically I want the user to do a input through the console and I want to finger out the first number and give it out on to the console, like for example:

```
hello465924whats334up // userinput
465924 // console output
```

this is basically the code that i have till now:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ZahlZusammenFueger {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter something!");
        String e = s.nextLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: Use Regex .*?([^a-z].*?).*?

Comment: Use a regular expression. Search the web to learn how they work, but what you want is: `Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(s.nextLine()); if (m.find()) System.out.println(m.group());`

Comment: Unclear at best. What if the input is `Blabla-124BlaBla`?

Comment: @Andreas has your most elegant solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that number is substring, find the indexes where it begins and where it ends. Like this:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter something!");
String e = s.nextLine();

while (!Character.isDigit(e.charAt(i))) i++; // finding index 
                                             // where substring of first number starts
j = i;
while (Character.isDigit(e.charAt(j))) j++; // finding index
                                            // where substring of first number ends
String number = e.substring(i, j));
```

Now, you can make `Integer` from it, or `Long` (depending on size) by doing this:

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(e.substring(i, j)));
System.out.println(Long.parseInt(e.substring(i, j)));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked.